# An inequality for normed vectorspaces

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be an euclidean vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$, $U_1, U_2$ subspaces of $V$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = W$. For $\mu \in U_2$ let $\mu_W$ be the projection of $\mu$ onto $W$. I want to understand the following implication:

The two maps $U_1 \times U_2 \rightarrow V$ given by
$$ (\lambda, \mu) \mapsto \lambda - \mu \quad \text{ and } \quad (\lambda, \mu) \mapsto \lambda - \mu_W $$
have the same kernel. *This implies* there is a constant $0 < c \leq 1$ such that for all $\lambda \in U_1, \mu \in U_2$
$$ \| \lambda - \mu\| \geq c (\| \lambda - \mu_W\| + \| \mu - \mu_W\| ).$$
It looks like this uses equivalence of norms on finite dimensional vector spaces but I seem to still miss a point. I would be grateful for any hint into the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ and $S$ be linear maps on a finite dimesnional space with the same kernel. Consider the map $Tx \to (Sx,(T-S)x)$. This is a well defined linear map on the range of $T$. Continuity of this map gives $\|Sx\|+\|Tx-Sx\| \leq C \|Tx\|$ for some $C \in (0,\infty)$. [You can use any norm on the product space and I am using the norm $\|u\|+\|v\|$]. When $T$ and $S$ are the two maps you have defined this gives the desired inequality.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.